# Turn a array of object with a nested object inside into a new array with values from the nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am trying to turn a array that exists of objects with a nested array inside it into a new array that consist of the values inside the nested array separately(Might sound very complicated but example show very clear)

What I have:

```
const values = [{
    geometry: {
      "coordinates": [11.4828, 59.1264],
      "Type": "point"
    },
    properties: {
      Region: "Oklahoma",
      sales: {
        donuts: {
          2005: 5,
          2006: 8,
          2007: 10
        },
        apples: {
          2005: 10,
          2006: 8,
          2007: 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    geometry: {
      "coordinates": [9.4828, 76.1264],
      "Type": "point"
    },
    properties: {
      Region: "Texas",
      sales: {
        donuts: {
          2005: 8,
          2006: 0,
          2007: 7
        },
        apples: {
          2005: 7,
          2006: 9,
          2007: 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
const filterValue = "donuts"
```

What My goal is:

```
newValues =[{geometry: {"coordinates": [11.4828, 59.1264],"Type":"point"},properties:{Region: "Oklahoma",value:5,time:2005}},{geometry: {"coordinates": [11.4828, 59.1264],"Type":"point"},properties:{Region: "Oklahoma",value:8,time:2006}},{geometry: {"coordinates": [11.4828, 59.1264],"Type":"point"},properties:{Region: "Oklahoma",value:10,time:2007}} AND SO ON FOR ALL THE values that are in const donuts/filter for each value. Could also switch out value for donuts if that is easier
}
]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
const newObject = []
values.map((value)=>{
  console.log(value.properties.sales.donuts)
  for (var key in value.properties.sales.donuts) {
        if (value.properties.sales.donuts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            newObject.push({...value,value.properties:{[key]:value.properties.sales.donuts[key]})
        }
    }
})
console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current syntax is invalid - `value.properties: {` is not a valid key in an object literal. Since you want the output `properties` property to contain data corresponding to the region and year too, you should include those in the object being pushed. Since you also don't need the year to be a *key* in the new object, but a *value* (with a `value` property), the object being pushed should reflect that.

You should only use `.map` when you're returning a value inside the mapper function to create a new array. If you're iterating only to perform side-effects, you should use a more appropriate generic iteration method, like `for..of` or `forEach`. In this case, since you want to create multiple objects in the output array from one associated object in the input array, `.flatMap` would be more appropriate.

Map the `.donuts` entries and return the new object with `geometry` and `properties` properties.

```js
const values=[{geometry:{coordinates:[11.4828,59.1264],Type:"point"},properties:{Region:"Oklahoma",sales:{donuts:{2005:5,2006:8,2007:10},apples:{2005:10,2006:8,2007:10}}}},{geometry:{coordinates:[9.4828,76.1264],Type:"point"},properties:{Region:"Texas",sales:{donuts:{2005:8,2006:0,2007:7},apples:{2005:7,2006:9,2007:4}}}}];

const filterValue = "donuts";
const output = values.flatMap(({ geometry, properties }) =>
    Object.entries(properties.sales[filterValue]).map(([year, saleCount]) => ({
        geometry,
        properties: {
            Region: properties.Region,
            value: saleCount,
            time: year,
        }
    }))
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: can `properties.sales.donuts` be changed to `properties.sales[filterValue]` instead for a dynamic option?

Comment: What are those comments? /**ref:3**/, is it possible to avoid them?

Comment: @matieva That's just an artifact of the Stack Snippet's console. Look at the results in the browser console instead - the output structure is as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a flatmap here

```js
const values = [
  {
    geometry: {
      coordinates: [11.4828, 59.1264],
      Type: 'point',
    },
    properties: {
      Region: 'Oklahoma',
      sales: {
        donuts: {
          2005: 5,
          2006: 8,
          2007: 10,
        },
        apples: {
          2005: 10,
          2006: 8,
          2007: 10,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    geometry: {
      coordinates: [9.4828, 76.1264],
      Type: 'point',
    },
    properties: {
      Region: 'Texas',
      sales: {
        donuts: {
          2005: 8,
          2006: 0,
          2007: 7,
        },
        apples: {
          2005: 7,
          2006: 9,
          2007: 4,
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
const mapData = (data, filterBy) => {
  return data.flatMap((state) => {
    return Object.entries(state.properties.sales[filterBy]).map(
      ([time, value]) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          properties: {
            region: state.properties.Region,
            time,
            value,
          },
        };
      }
    );
  });
};

const mappedDonuts = mapData(values, 'donuts');
console.log(mappedDonuts);
```

Comment: I would not like it like that. I would like to have each year in a different Object. So it ends up like something this: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson

Comment: ah, I see! I have updated the code according to your desired data format.